# GCC GAS jmp to a memory value without using registers (relative jmp)

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

how to jump in GCC inline asm without passing the value to a register?

this code

```
__asm__("jmp %0"::"r"(&_start))
```

generates:

```
mov    eax,0x1011
jmp    eax
```

but instead i want

```
jmp 0x1011
```

or just `jmp +0x11`,

- tried using `"m"` instead of `"r"` and produces: `memory input 0 is not directly addressable`.

how can i just obtain a jump instruction without the overhead of using a register?
Is this even possible with GCC inline asm?

Comment: Is `jmp .+0x11` what you want? Or maybe `"m" (_start)` without the `&`? What is `_start`?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#GenericOperandmodifiers - `jmp %l0` with an `"i"(_start)` constraint probably works.  Something like that.

Comment: Or `%p0` for a raw symbol name (or numeric address) from an `"i"(_start)` constraint.  Or `&_start` I guess if it's not something that is an address if you use the bare name, like a function declaration or `extern char _start[]`

Comment: @Jester _start is a function., that is a function entry point to call _start, it has no return, so no reason to use call and i have information on register to pass on _start, this jmp function is just an experiment to hijack and override the stack pointer before starting a kernel

Comment: @PeterCordes yes with the `i` i achieved what i wanted.

Comment: Not really sure if this can be that duplicate question though as this is using `jmp`. Ok conceptually the `i` part is the same, but it won't appear in searches, infact i didn't find at all that question.

Comment: It's a duplicate because the non-trivial part is getting GCC to print the symbol name in the asm template, rather than a register name.  This question is a signpost for people looking for it with `jmp` instead of `call`.  That's the point of the duplicate system on stack overflow, why it's a closure reason not a deletion.